# how to force user to insert some value into a @htmel.textbox using jquery in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a search page in which i want to force user to insert some valid input using jquery what i was trying is not working, please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn-gn').click(function () {
            if ($('#firstName').length == 0) {
                alert("please enter username");
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search","User")',
                type: 'POST'
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            });   //end ajax
        });
</script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "User", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  @Html.TextBox("firstName", null, new { @class = "complete" })
 @Html.TextBox("lastName", null, new { @class ="complete" })
  <button type="submit" id="btn-gn">submit</button>

    }
```

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you clarify how it is not working?

Comment: You could also use  [Required(ErrorMessage="Name Required")] in your model on required fields, and submit your form asynchronously. It would be a more secure validation. Back end validation always is.

Comment: @Rhumborl yeah it is firstname by mistake i typed wrong.

Comment: @Brian Tompsett when those textboxes are blank and i select the submit button its simply send me to the redirected index page.that i dont want i want to stay at the same page when nothing is inserted into the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things which need changing:

1. `$('#firstName').length` simply checks if there is an element with `id="firstName"` on the page. You want to check if they have entered something in the box so you need `val()`, i.e. `if($('#firstName').val().length == 0)`.
2. If they do not enter a name, you are alerting them but not stopping anything from happening. If you simply add `return false;` after the alert, this will stop the ajax and also stop the form from being submitted.
3. Similarly, the default action for the button is to submit the form. This is still happening, which is why you are being redirected to the index page and your ajax is ignored. Again a simple `return false;` at the end of the function or better `event.preventDefault()` should handle this.
4. It looks like your script comes before the element, so jquery cannot find `btn-gn` and nothing is being bound. If you put the whole script in a jquery call `$(function() { ... })`, it will run when the DOM is ready and the button exists on the page.
5. Lastly, checking the button click should work ok, but it is safer to handle the `form.submit` event, as this will be triggered by pressing the button, but can potentially also be triggered by other things.

This should work better for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // wrap it in a jquery call so it runs on document ready
    $(function() {
        // find the form and listen to the submit event
        $('#btn-gn').closest('form').on('submit', function () {
            event.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting

            if ($('#firstName').val().length == 0) {
                alert("please enter username");
                return; // exit the function so ajax doesn't happen
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search","User")',
                type: 'POST'
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            });   //end ajax
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBox("firstName", null, new { @class = "complete" })
    @Html.TextBox("lastName", null, new { @class ="complete" })
    <button type="submit" id="btn-gn">submit</button>
}
```